# Segmented Control is not getting attached to its boundary

Tags: ios, swift, background, uisegmentedcontrol, boundary

I have created a `UISegmentedControl` in the `UIStoryboard` but it is not attaching to its background. The issue is shown below. Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance!.
[image]

I have given the constraints like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the constraints you set for this?

Comment: What are the constrains that you've added to the segment control?

Comment: Actually that white background colour is the colour of segmentControl background. My issue is, the segment control UI is not getting filled into its background @ShreeramBhat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue I found. I have solved this issue by setting the auto-size in the size inspector to Equal widths.